# Append element to boost::python::tuple

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-tuples

I'm trying to remove the second element from a `boost::python::tuple` object. The tuple from which I want to remove the second element is the list of arguments passed to a Python function call.

To remove the element I do like this:

```
BPY::object CallMethod(BPY::tuple args, BPY::dict kwargs)
{
    ...

    // args is my original tuple from which I want to remove the second element

    boost::python::api::object_slice firstSlice = args.slice(0, 1);
    boost::python::tuple newArgs = boost::python::extract<boost::python::tuple>(firstSlice);

    if(boost::python::len(args) > 2)
    {
        boost::python::api::object_slice secondSlice = args.slice(2, boost::python::len(args));
        boost::python::tuple secondSliceArgs = boost::python::extract<boost::python::tuple>(secondSlice);

        newArgs = boost::python::make_tuple(newArgs, secondSliceArgs);
    }

    args = newArgs;

    ...
}
```

I think that the problem is that `boost::python::tuple` doesn't add the element,
but it created a new tuple with the first and second slices as elements.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Silly question. I just needed to do it like this (to concatenate two tuples): `newArgs = BPY::extract<BPY::tuple>(newArgs + secondSliceArgs);`

Answer (score 0):

`tuple` is an immutable data structure in Python, unlike `list`.